# In Ruby, for an undefined variable "foo", why doesn't "foo = foo" raise an error?

Tags: ruby

When `foo` is an undefined variable, attempting to access it raises a `NameError`:

```
foo
#=> NameError: undefined local variable or method `foo'

a = foo
#=> NameError: undefined local variable or method `foo'
```

Why doesn't `foo = foo` raise a `NameError`?

```
foo = foo
#=> nil
```

Yesterday, it took me hours to track down this line as the bug in a program...

```
capture = capture.to_i
```

What I had intended to do was convert `capture_str` to an `Integer`.  What I had done instead was introduce a `nil` by saying `capture = capture`, and then turning that nil into a `0`.  So I was doing this...

```
capture = capture.to_i
#=> 0
```

But I had been incorrectly assuming that a variable `NameError` would have been thrown, like this...

```
capture = capture_str.to_i
#=> NameError: undefined local variable or method `capture_str'
```

Comment: The docs for [Assignment](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/doc/syntax/assignment_rdoc.html#label-Local+Variables+and+Methods) mention it briefly: _"The local variable is created when the parser encounters the assignment, not when the assignment occurs"_

Comment: It's a weird behavior indeed. You could use the [`Kernel#Integer`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Kernel.html#method-i-Integer)  method and write `capture = Integer(capture)` to make sure it fails when `capture` doesn't look like an integer : `"5.3"`, `nil` or `""` for example.

Comment: BTW, calling `to_i` even if the receiver could be `nil` might not be the best approach. Can you show more of your code? There's probably a cleaner way to solve this.

Comment: @EricDuminil The tip about `Interger(foo)` is super useful, thanks.  That helped quite a bit to simplify the code.  I am already using it :)

Comment: The link given by @Stefan contains a goldmine of information and is very well-written, worth a careful read by all Rubyists.

Answer (score 14):

Ruby has this weird *feature* that it hoists variables when they're declared:

> This means that when the parser sees x=1, it will actually declare the variable, by assigning it to nil and let the interpreter then figure out if the x = 1 line will ever get executed.

[source](https://ieftimov.com/post/variable-hoisting-ruby/)

So when you write

```
a = a.to_i
```

it first declare `a = nil` then calls `to_i` on it and the assigns:

```
a = nil
a = a.to_i
```

EDIT:

It also works like that in other cases, e.g. with `if`:

```
pry> b
NameError: undefined local variable or method `b' for main:Object
from (pry):30:in `__pry__'
pry> b if b.nil?
NameError: undefined local variable or method `b' for main:Object
from (pry):31:in `__pry__'
pry> b = 1 if b.nil?
#=> 1
pry> b
#=> 1
```

and (example from the linked blogpost):

```
if false
  x = 1
end
puts x.class
# NilClass
```